# Microsoft Access: How to change keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been trying to change the keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Access, but I haven't found any such feature in the options menu and googling it proved fruitless.

Specifically, I want to change the keyboard shortcut for switching between Design/Form/Datasheet views.

Does anybody know a way to change these keyboard shortcuts or do I just have to live with pressing a 4-key combo everytime I want to switch views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at a form to flip into design mode I use ctrl-,

When I make changes, then I like to ALWAYS save my work, so I hit ctrl-w. At this point in time the form still should be highlighted on the ribbon, so I hit enter to launch the form.

And from any object selected in the nav pane, then I hit ctrl-enter to jump right into design mode.

You can also hit ctrl-, several times to “cycle” through all the views – but design, layout etc. takes too many keystrokes – but give it a try anyway.

I explain this “developer” dance with some tips here:

http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/navpne/NavTips.html

You can setup some auto keys macro, but since you ALWAYS (and I mean ALWAYS) starting the application by holding down the shift key during start up to develop your application (as opposed to running it with start-up options), then I don’t recommend setting up auto Keys since you as a developer really must by-pass all start up settings if you going to have a sane developer experience.

So while auto keys is great for the “user” mode of your application, and re-mapping keys for “running” the application. However during the development process I recommend you avoid auto keys – it will interfere with your development process.

There are a good many single key shortcuts you can use to flip into design mode.

If you looking for "user" settings, then autokeys is fine. However for development, then all the settings that hides so much of the Access UI will likely be enabled - and shift key by-pass thus becomes a necessity to work and develop on that application.